# CSS and HTML only dropdown spoiler

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I am trying to create a CSS and HTML drop-down spoiler with open animation.

I started from this 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERAFY/x8FQJ/1/) 
but `margin-top:-100%;` doesn't work very well.

```
margin-top:-100%;
```

Any solution for smooth animated dropdown container?

Comment: what results are you looking to get? can you define how it's not working the way you'd like it to? I don't see anything wrong with the fiddle.

Comment: No, it dosent work! "inside" block move to hight and as result delay for show animation.
 http://jsfiddle.net/alex_qt_12312/x8FQJ/289/

Answer (score 1):

You have some error in your CSS. You specified `.spoiler > div` for **show state** and only `.spoiler` for **hide state**. You should specify the same thing for both and the animation will run smoothly.

```css
.spoilerbutton {
    display:block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.spoiler {
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.spoiler > div {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: margin 0.2s ease;
}
.spoilerbutton[value="Show"] + .spoiler > div {
    margin-top:-100%;
}
.spoilerbutton[value="Hide"] + .spoiler > div {
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<input class="spoilerbutton" type="button" value="Show" onclick="this.value=this.value=='Show'?'Hide':'Show';">
<div class="spoiler"><div>
PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE
    PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE
    PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE
    PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE
    PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE
    PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE
</div></div>
```

By the way You can also animate the `max-height` instead of `margin` like this :

```css
.spoilerbutton {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.spoiler {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.spoiler>div {
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.spoilerbutton[value="Show"]+.spoiler>div {
  max-height: 0;
}

.spoilerbutton[value="Hide"]+.spoiler>div {
  max-height: 90px; /*use a big value here*/
}
```

```html
<input class="spoilerbutton" type="button" value="Show" onclick="this.value=this.value=='Show'?'Hide':'Show';">
<div class="spoiler">
  <div>
    PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE PUT CONTENT YOU WISH TO HIDE HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know max-height for my block, it may be dynamically.

Comment: There's a "problem" with your solution. The bigger you set max-height, the bigger the delay will be between the click and the hide animation actually hiding the element.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro it's not a problem, but when you make the value very big it will take to long to make it back to 0 ... so my intent was to make it bigger enough as the height and not less but also not very big .. i update will lower value, but you can try to change it and you will notice this

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know, that's why it's in quotes, but it's still a drawback...

Comment: Its huge problem on mobile devices were height of block may be 1000px for example.
http://jsfiddle.net/alex_qt_12312/x8FQJ/289/

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro yes sure it has some drawback ;) by the way by using only CSS it's very hard to make things very precise

Answer (score -1):

For smooth animated dropdown container, maybe you can try this :

```
    .spoiler > div {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: margin 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I hope his help you ! Am I answering your question?

Comment: NO, try set it ti 2s and you can see delays.